# How to find out if sum of square roots is a perfect(-ish) square: $\sum_{i=0}^m \sqrt{x_i} = \bigl(\sum_{j=0}^n \sqrt{y_j}\bigr)^2$?

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

I'm writing [a Python library](https://pypi.org/project/symba) that deals with symbolic computations of square roots (since approximated ones cause a lot of problems and at least for now correctness is more valuable than performance).

As a part of this I need to be able to simplify square root of sums of square roots, i.e. find if sum of square roots is representable as an another sum of square roots squared:
$$
\exists y_j\in \mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0}:\quad\sum_{i=0}^m \sqrt{x_i} = \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \sqrt{y_j} \right)^2
$$
where $x_i \in \mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0}$ are known.

For example:
$$
\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{9} = 2\sqrt{2} + 3 = \left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2}\right)^2
$$

After expanding right-hand side
$$
\left( \sum_{j=0}^n \sqrt{y_j} \right)^2 = \sum_{j=0}^n y_j + 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n - 1} \sum_{k=j + 1}^{n} \sqrt{y_j} \sqrt{y_k}
$$
we can see that it is required for the left-hand side to have one term which is a square root of a perfect square, i.e. a rational number.

I've managed to implement algorithm for two terms, but can't find any general approach, so my question is: does it exist?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not always possible even in simple cases, for example, $m=0$ and $x_0=2$.

Comment: @GregMartin: yes, I understand, the question is about how to find out whether it is possible (and as a next step -- how to find this representation)